# How to make editplus "Find in Files" but exclude those in .svn directories?

Tags: text-editors

Anyone here knows the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can exclude all svn directories in editplus by adding .svn in "Exclude"
Please look the screenshot below
http://picpaste.com/editplus_search-jdIYchMr.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Search > Find in files
2. Include the file types you want with, for example `*.ext` (or * for all files, including files without file extensions)
3. Filter out the filetypes you'd like to exclude. This field supports
   multiple exclusion criteria by separating the filters with
   semicolons. For example: `*.dll;*.pdb;*.exe;*.msi`

Answer (score -1):

Just type svn in exclude textbox, it will match keyword to any pathname it has sought. However directory name with space doesn't work here. You just have to find a unique keyword within the directory name you want to exclude (Maybe there's a way to type that space, you have to ask developers of Editplus).